# what version of .Net Framework comes with Windows 2008 R2

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

Which .net framework is coming by default with fresh install of 2008 R2? frameowkr 2.0 or 3.5 or nothing. IF i need to enable 3.5 manually means everything is already there installed by default, i need to just enable it or i need to install?

Comment: It is .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 - you should be good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which operating systems come with .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390/which-operating-systems-come-with-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: [what version of .Net Framework comes with Windows 2008 R2?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2webtechnologies/thread/ac1bf719-0a88-4b5d-be98-395f2623e805)

Windows Server 2008 R2 includes .Net Framework 3.5 with SP1. You need to install it `from --> Server Manager --> Features --> .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features.`

By default, the system comes with .Net Framwork Setup v2.0.50727 installed. You can verify it via the following registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
- Version REG_SZ 2.0.50727
```

Check ServerFault Thread - https://serverfault.com/questions/149415/exactly-which-net-version-does-windows-server-2008-r2-core-support  and  SO Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390/which-operating-systems-come-with-net
for more information.

Comment: ,okey when i tried to install framework 2.0 it showing error "this product will supported on a 64 bit operating system"?

Comment: download x64 version of installer and then try to install

Answer (score 2):

From: [What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx) By: [Aaron Stebner](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/aaron%20stebner/)

> Windows Server 2008 R2 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework
>   3.5.1 as an OS component.  This means you will get the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 plus a few post 3.5 SP1 bug fixes.  3.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features
>   control panel.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390/which-operating-systems-come-with-net

Apparently .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Search is your friend ;)

Comment: okey when i tried to install framework 2.0 it showing error "this product will supported on a 64 bit operating system"?

Comment: A quick google reveals the x64 version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6523